# Initialising an instance of a class, getting unexpected output/result of that

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to initialize a new instance of my class DFA, but it does not give me the desired answer I wanted.

Here is my DFA class:

```
class DFA {
    private nodes: { label: string, attributes?: string[] }[]
    private alphabet: any[]
    private edges: (string | string[])[][]

    constructor(
        nodes: { label: string, attributes?: string[] }[],
        alphabet: any[],
        edges: (string | string[])[][],
    ) {
        this.nodes = nodes
        this.alphabet = alphabet
        this.edges = edges
    }
}
```

And here is the data, that I use to create a new instance of the DFA class:

```
const result = { "nodes": [{ "label": "a", "attributes": ["initial"] }, { "label": "b", "attributes": [] }, { "label": "c", "attributes": ["accept"] }], "edges": [["a", "a", ["1"]], ["a", "b", ["0"]], ["b", "a", ["1"]], ["b", "c", ["0"]], ["c", "c", ["0, 1"]]] };
```

So now that I have defined the DFA class and I got the data that I need in order to make a new instance of DFA, I then proceed to do it as follows:

```
const Machine = new DFA(result.nodes, getAlphabet(), result.edges);
```

The `getAlphabet()` function, does not matter, how its made. But then when I `console.log(Machine)` I get:

```
DFA { 
nodes: 
     [ {label: 'a', attributes: [Object] },
       {label: 'b', attributes: [] },
       {label: 'c', attributes: [Object] }, ],
alphabet: ['1', '0'], 
edges: 
     [ ['a', 'a', [Object] ],
       ['a', 'b', [Object] ], 
       ['b', 'a', [Object] ],
       ['b', 'c', [Object] ],
       ['c', 'c', [Object] ] ] 
}
```

Which is not the result that I expected or want, for that matter. 
What I want my result/output to look like is:

```
[ {label: 'a', attributes: [ 'initial' ] },
  {label: 'b', attributes: [] },
  {label: 'c', attributes: [ 'accept' ] }, ]
...
edges: 
     [ ['a', 'a', ['1'] ],
       ['a', 'b', ['0'] ], 
       ['b', 'a', ['1'] ],
       ['b', 'c', ['0'] ],
       ['c', 'c', ['0, 1'] ] ]
```

So does anyone know what I am doing wrong? and how to fix it? or have I simply misunderstood something?

Comment: Arrays are objects. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(Machine))`

Comment: You are the real MVP! That did the job!